# Get country code using Bing Maps REST API

Tags: windows-phone-7, geocoding, bing-maps

I am a WP7 developer. I have longitude and latitude of a location and getting complete information defined by the coordinate ie longitude and latitude by using Bing maps API

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/37.09024,-95.712891?o=json&key=APIKEY
```

Above latitude and longitude is USA location, I'm able to get `addressLine`,`adminDistrict`,`adminDistrict2`,`countryRegion`,`formattedAddress` and `postalCode` but not `country code(ISO ALPHA-2 Code) like IN for India, US for United States`, `countryRegion` in json response consists country name, My app limitation is to use country code not country name.Did anything i missed in API url. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a seperate parameter "incl=ciso2" for country code as it comes under additional info. Modify your query string like this.
        http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/37.09024,-95.712891?incl=ciso2&o=json&key=APIKEY.

Doing this you will have an additonal field in the address object "countryregioniso2" which will have the 2 digit country code.

Answer (score 0):

The field name if you have added &incl=ciso2 to url will be "countryRegionIso2" and this still works.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you consider using the Geonames countrycode service instead.

Documentation: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrycode

Example: http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=37.09024&lng=-95.712891&username=demo